# which permissions are needed to execute GetWebPartProperties2

Tags: web-services

GetWebPartProperties2 method of WebPartPagesWebService works when the user has admin rights. Can this method work without full admin rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user can not do it through the SharePoint interface (the actual SharePoint web site) it can not be done by running code (under those credentials) either.

However it's possible to run a piece of your code with higher permissions by using the 'RunWithElevatedPrivileges' method. You don't want all your code to run under 'elevated privileges' only the part that executes the 'GetWebPartProperties2' method. Here is a sample:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(web.Site.ID))
    {
    // implementation details omitted
    }
});
```

There are a few things to know about elevating your code and getting objects. 
 For more info see: 
http://sharepointquicksolutions.blogspot.be/2012/11/all-ways-of-runwithelevatedprivileges.html